# sed over ssh doesn't escape backslash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed

I'm trying to add a line before "rezhome" in the file as it would look like below:

```
...
app3-reservation, \
app4-reservation, \
app5-reservation, \
rezhome
```

When I run locally with below command it works fine.

```
sed -i 's/rezhome/app5-reservation, \\\n&/' grouphost.cfg
```

But using ssh backslash is not escaped and I get below result

```
ssh localhost "sed -i 's/rezhome/app5-reservation, \\\n&/' /path/grouphost.cfg"

...
app3-reservation, \
app4-reservation, \
app5-reservation, \nrezhome
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\` gets processed by both the `sed` and the `ssh` so you'll need to further escape them to use it with both.  Try:

```
 ssh localhost "sed -i 's/rezhome/app5-reservation, \\\\\n&/' /path/grouphost.cfg"
```